# Get MySQL performance

Tags: java, php, python, mysql

It's posible to get the performance of my MySQL Database like queries/sec, writes/sec, slow queries, number of connections. Using Python, PHP or Java?

Without using New Relic or similar alternatives.

I can't find anything on Google.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a standard technology to do this that writes to a file, and then read it in with your favourite language.

Comment: Try `SHOW /*!50002 GLOBAL */ STATUS LIKE 'Com\_%';` and read more about it in the MYSQL documentation. Also there is a flag called: `slow_query_log` that logs slow queries in a logfile.

Comment: You want to test your DAO layer or directly the DB ? If it's directly the DB, why not use a test program like JMeter ?

Answer (score 1):

This is all available through a simple query, as outlined [in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-status.html), you will need to do some periodic polling and time series analysis to calculate rates.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS;
+--------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name            | Value      |
+--------------------------+------------+
| Aborted_clients          | 0          |
| Aborted_connects         | 0          |
| Bytes_received           | 155372598  |
| Bytes_sent               | 1176560426 |
| Connections              | 30023      |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables  | 0          |
| Created_tmp_tables       | 8340       |
| Created_tmp_files        | 60         |
...
| Open_tables              | 1          |
| Open_files               | 2          |
| Open_streams             | 0          |
| Opened_tables            | 44600      |
| Questions                | 2026873    |
...
| Table_locks_immediate    | 1920382    |
| Table_locks_waited       | 0          |
| Threads_cached           | 0          |
| Threads_created          | 30022      |
| Threads_connected        | 1          |
| Threads_running          | 1          |
| Uptime                   | 80380      |
+--------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I can't have the mysql credentials. Is there a way to do this without knowing the user and password?